# Should we have a list of programming languages created by our users?

Tags: discussion

### Update: the list can now be found [here](https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350/what-languages-have-been-created-by-pldi-users).

Code Golf has a [list](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6918/107299) of languages created by users of that site. However, nearly all of them are either golfing or esoteric languages. I imagine if we were to create a list here there would be a lot more practical and perhaps interesting languages submitted. I myself have a practical language I haven't showed off yet. So, should we make one or not?

Comment: Would be a list be on meta or on the site itself?

Comment: Probably on the site itself

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Policy on advertising programming languages](https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74/policy-on-advertising-programming-languages)

Comment: The post should either be on meta or community wiki'd. You shouldn't be able to gain rep from promoting your langauge

Comment: @mousetail agree

Comment: This appears to exist now - https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350/what-languages-have-been-created-by-pldi-users - though I am unclear what magic was used to create it.

Comment: @BruceAdams it appears to have been done by Rydwolf, who owns that bot

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Yes

From each poster's side, it's nice to show off your own work, and it could help people learn about and potentially use your language(s).

From the perspective of someone looking at the thread, it could help you discover languages you might not have known about and provide inspiration for your own work, and if you've answered their questions on the main site you might get to see your help in action.

Answer (score 2):

I think such a list would be useful to have on meta, since it helps to showcase the breadth of experience in our community, which may make others more interested in joining.

Answer (score -4):

Absolutely, for the reason that the answers said. But we need to have some requirements to prevent spam. First, maybe you might need a certain amount of people who like your language to have it shown. As Wikipedia said, we don't need an essay on your garage band to be publicly displayed to thousands of people.

Comment: Why do you think there would be spam?

Comment: Imagine from the spammers perspective:"I can now advertise my things and show it to thousands of people for free and it will be actively encouraged and no one has to even like it for me to be able to advertise. Yeah!" @Seggan

Comment: That's the whole point of the showcase is it not? To show off your fancy new language that nobody even heard of. See the Code Golf list; almost nobody heard of the langs that are posted there, but there is no spam. In any case, spam can be handled end by mods.

Comment: I don't know about anyone else, but I don't get paid royalties any time someone uses one of my languages. There is no financial incentive for me to "advertise", let alone spam.